# Coriolis effect, angle between beaches

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, coriolis-effect

I'm having some trouble with the following question:
A river has width a and floats on the latitude θ on Earth with the speed v. Due to the Coriolis force, the water surface will tilt. How much height difference h will it be between the two beaches? (The Coriolis acceleration can be assumed much smaller than the gravitational acceleration, and the answer is given to linear order in Ωv/g, where Ω is the angular velocity of the Earth's diurnal rotation.)

So I'm supposed to find the height difference between the beaches. But to do so I need to find the angle between them in the form of theta. That's where I'm lost. The answer should be (2Ωv/g)*a* sin(theta). But I don't know how to find the angle between them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by the "angle between them" What is "them"?

The vertical component of the  diurnal  angular velocity at latitude $\theta$ is $\Omega \sin \theta$, so the transverse Coriolis force per unit mass is $2\Omega v\sin\theta$. Consequently  the tilt of the water surface  is  $\arctan (2\Omega v\sin\theta/g)$.

Comment: And $2\Omega v/g\sin(\theta)$ is really quite small so this can be approximated by just $2\Omega v/g\sin(\theta)$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got it to arctan(2Ωsin/)? I can't seem to figure it out geometricaly.

Answer (score -1):

Using the coriolis force and gravitational force combined, simply find the total potential on a cross section of the river $U(x, z)$, the water's surface will always form an equipotential line.

Comment: You're kind of right, but it might be useful to give some detail on how to construct a potential for the Coriolis force in this case. The Coriolis force doesn't nominally have any potential associated with it, since it doesn't do any work (like a magnetic field).